# codeigniter admin panel automatic page creation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create one controller file which is creating automatically a function if i create a menu dynamically and also want to create view page which is connencted to this main controller.. how to do that?

Current code:

```
public function our_history() 
      { 
          $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang'); 
          $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang'); 
          $this->load->view('vwMain',$data);//Left Menu } 
      }
```

Comment: please reply in a code

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: unable to understand...:-(

Comment: like I have the controller main.php
and the function is like that

    public function our_history()
    {
        $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
        $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');

        $this->load->view('vwMain',$data);//Left Menu
    }

now I want the function name have to come or fetch from database..like suppose menu is a table name and menutitle is a feild name then i want to fetch the menutitles as the function name in the place of our_history... is it possible?

Comment: please rply in a code

Comment: no i want to replace our_history to the datas from feild named menutitle of menu table...I mean i want the name of function is dynamic...is it possible?

Comment: but you need to have method to handle the request.

Comment: You cannot pass tablename and field name in url.Thats a bad practice.

Comment: ok then please write code of controller...as i am a newcomer in ci..

Comment: What is purpose of doing so ? that is creating a function by its menu handle name ? is there any special reson or something like you just wnat to display the static pages over those handels that is menu items ?

Comment: actually i want to create page dynamically..my logic is when i create a menu from admin panel then a page is created means by clicking the menu a page including header n footer must be shown ...how to do that

Comment: So basically your need is to create the static pages where admin can create or manage static pages for different url and all of them having same layout, Not to create a function for every page

Comment: yes...but the page name means the url should be the title of the menu from menu table.Yes the page layout should be same

Comment: how to code that..please help

Comment: wait a few min. I will post the flow that how it could be acheived

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta -  post a sample url. when menu is clicked

Comment: @Bugfixer sample url is like localhost/foldername/classname/menutitle(dyanamic from database)

Answer (score 5):

Follow below steps Hope that makes sense.
-- Admin section --

/*content.php -- controller starts here */

```
class Content extends VCI_Controller {

# Class constructor
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('content_model');
}

/*
Add page logic
*/
function edit_page($id = null)
{

    $this->_vci_layout('your_layoutname');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $view_data = array();

    //Set the view caption
    $view_data['caption'] = "Edit Content";

    //Set the validation rules for server side validation
    // rule name editcontent should be defined

    if($this->form_validation->run('editcontent')) {

        //Everything is ok lets update the page data
        if($this->content_model->update(trim($id))) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "<li>Page has been edited successfully.</li>");
            $this->output->set_header('location:' . base_url() . 'content/manage_content');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "<li>Unknown Error: Unable to edit page.</li>");
            $this->output->set_header('location:' . base_url() . 'content/manage_content');
        }

    } else {

        $page = $this->content_model->get_content_page(trim($id)); 
        $view_data["id"] = $page->id;
        $view_data["page_title"] = $page->page_title;
        $view_data["page_menu_slug"] = $page->page_menu_slug;
        $view_data["page_name"] = $page->page_name;
        $view_data["page_content"] = $page->page_content;
        $view_data["status"] = $page->status;
        $this->_vci_view('content_editpage', $view_data);
    }
}

/*
Edit page logic
*/
function add_page()
{

    $this->_vci_layout('your_layoutname');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $view_data = array();

    $view_data['caption'] = "Edit Content";

    if($this->form_validation->run('editcontent')) { 
        // after passing validation rule data to be saved
        // editcontent rule must be defined in formvalidations file

        //Everything is ok lets update the page data
        if($this->content_model->add()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "<li>Page has been edited successfully.</li>");
            $this->output->set_header('location:' . base_url() . 'content/manage_content');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "<li>Unknown Error: Unable to edit page.</li>");
            $this->output->set_header('location:' . base_url() . 'content/manage_content');
        }

    } else {

        $page = $this->content_model->get_content_page(trim($id)); 
        $view_data["id"] = $page->id;
        $view_data["page_title"] = $page->page_title;
        $view_data["page_menu_slug"] = $page->page_menu_slug;
        $view_data["page_name"] = $page->page_name;
        $view_data["page_content"] = $page->page_content;
        $view_data["status"] = $page->status;
        $this->_vci_view('content_editpage', $view_data);
    }
}
```

}
/**
* content.php -- controller ends here
*/

/*
Content_model starts here
*/

```
class Content_model extends CI_Model {

// update logic goes here
function update($id = null) {
    if(is_null($id)) {
        return false;
    }

    $data = array(
        'page_title' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('page_title',true)),
        'page_name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('page_name',true)),
        'page_content' => $this->input->post('page_content',true),
        'page_menu_slug' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('page_menu_slug',true)),
        'status' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('status',true))
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('content', $data);
    return true;

}

// Add logic goes here
function add() {
    $data = array(
        'page_title' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('page_title',true)),
        'page_name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('page_name',true)),
        'page_content' => $this->input->post('page_content',true),
        'page_menu_slug' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('page_menu_slug',true)),
        'status' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('status',true))
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->insert('content', $data);
    return true ;
}
```

}
/*
Content_model ends here # Admin section changes ends here 
*/
-- Add view files also to admin section  content_editpage.php

Now go to your routes.php file for front section --
add below line at last --

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/view_usingslug/$1';
```

This will be for all `urls like --- http://yourdomainname/your_slug_name`

// create again a controller in front section page.php --

```
class page extends VCI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function view_usingslug($slug='')
    {
        // retrieve the data by slug from content table using any model class and assign result to $view_dat
        $this->_vci_view('page',$view_data);
        //page.php will be your view file
    }

}
```

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta do U still need files ? or problem is resolved, basically that file would be your html file and you can display your data <?php echo $page_content ; ?> in your page.php file

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Your URL is

> www.example.com/controllername/methodname/menutitle1

or

> www.example.com/controllername/methodname/menutitle2

So this is how you handle these pages.

```
public function method()
{
   $menutitle = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $query = $this->db->get_where('TableName',array('Menutitle'=>$menutitle))
   $data['content'] = $query->row()->page_content;
   $this->load->view('common_page',$data);

}
```

Comment: @Srrijita Dasgupta : You can accept answer,if that really helped.

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta - click on right symbol below answer to accept.